# PulseAudio: list-codec and set-codec result in "Missing implementation"

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, codecs

I have a ThinkPad P14s Gen4 AMD and running latest (k)ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
I also own a pair of LG Tone FP9.

I came across the news that PulseAudio now supports AptX and wanted to make use of this.

While trying to query the available codecs, the command returns "Missing implementation"

```
$ pactl send-message /card/bluez_card.XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/bluez list-codec
Send message failed: Missing implementation
```

Same for setting the codec:

```
$ pactl send-message /card/bluez_card.XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/bluez set-codec '"aptx"'
Send message failed: Missing implementation
```

The FP9 do support AptX and I can verify the version of PulseAudio is > 15

```
$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 15.99.1
```

Does anyone has an idea where to dig deeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ pactl send-message /card/bluez_card.XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/bluez list-codecs
```

and this:

```
$ pactl send-message /card/bluez_card.XX_XX_XX_XX_XX_XX/bluez switch-codec '"aptx"'
```

Comment: I feel stupid now... No idea why I didn't use the correct commands. Thanks! :)